# What server URL should one provide for TeamCity agent in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, continuous-integration, teamcity

**The problem**. I am trying to create a *TeamCity* infrastructure (a server and an agent) on *Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 LTS* using *Docker*. I have run a *Docker* container with *jetbrains/teamcity-server* image as described on [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-server/). It is possible to access the *TeamCity* server via web browser using the IP address of the server and port 8111.

Now I try to run a *Docker* container with an agent as described on [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/). It is written: Note that "localhost" will not generally not work as that will refer to the "localhost" inside the container. Well, when I supply "http://localhost:8111", or "http://127.0.0.1:8111", or "http://my_server_ip:8111" to the running script for the agent container I finally get 1) "WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Error registering on the server via URL http://localhost:8111 (*sic! always localhost*). Will continue repeating connection attempts.", or 2) "WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Error while asking server for the communication protocols via URL http://localhost:8111/app/agents/protocols."

Also I have tried to reveal the IP address of the *Docker* container running the server and supply it for the agent running script. But the result was the same.

**Question**. What server URL I should provide? Are there any implicit steps in the *TeamCity* configuration with *Docker* which I miss?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `--link` parameter to link containers:

1. Start your `jetbrains/teamcity-server` and use `--name teamcity-server` to give it a descriptive name
2. Start the agent container and use `--link teamcity-server` to enable connectivity to the `teamcity-server` container
3. Inside of your agent container you can now use `teamcity-server` as the hostname to connect to the `teamcity-server` container

Please also check out [Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) which superseded the `--link` feature.

Comment: In your `teamcity-agent` now you could reference the linked `teamcity-server` container (in my case, I named teamcity) + using the **internal port 8111**. Like this `SERVER_URL=http://teamcity:8111`

Comment: I had the volume mapped to my host machine for the agent container. The agent connected to the server only after setting the serverUrl in buildAgent.properties file. When ever I run the container, it reads the properties from this file and so the environment variable is ignored.